# How to get info from the Apple iTunes «App Store» and «Mac App Store»

Tags: xml, api, app-store, itunes

I'm searching a solution to get all the information/retrieve all data from the iTunes «App Store» and «Mac App Store» from Apple to a given App-ID … Is there a way to read out all the infos like App-Description, Price, Icon, Developer, Ratings etc. from the Stores?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try using the **iTunes Search API** which will give you a nice JSON object representing the app. The *lookup section* is the one you are looking for:
[https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/#lookup)

Example query for the *Stack Overflow App*: 
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1155618808

Comment: The most interesting item, the name of the App seems mysteriously missing from this json result. Any tips on how to get that?

Comment: trackName is the name of the app and should be included in the json result (and it is in my example).

Comment: This is the correct answer for those looking to get all data about their own apps from the store without resorting to scraping.

Comment: Do anyone know how to get the version history given the app id? Just like Appshopper did.

Comment: Still some data is missing, like if an app has in app purchases or not, right?

Comment: this doesn't always work, anybody knows why?

Comment: apparently you have to specify the country if it's not available in the US AppStore. Example: http://itunes.apple.com/it/lookup?id=xxx

Comment: Is it possible to get url of the preview video?

Answer (score 9):

You can get all details from apple itunes using this url:
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=xxx&country=us&entity=software

Where you can get json object as result. So you can get all details of every app in apple itunes by decode the json object.

I think [this](http://www.phponwebsites.com/2015/03/get-app-details-from-apple-itunes-using-php.html) url will help you.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what seems to be the state of affairs as of 23-May-2011:

1. Lookup by id, as in ChaosCoder's example, seems to work for the Mac App Store.
2. Searching does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The type 'app' does not exist. Use 'Software'.