# iTunes App Store Web Scraping

Tags: php, screen-scraping, itunes, extract

I'm looking to have a user enter an app ID on a website, save the information from their app (my sql database), and then display that information on the website.

If anyone would mind sharing the code/process that would be used to do this or are there tutorials that you can point me in the direction of learning how to do this?

If you could help me out at all I will be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, there is a website called toucharcade.com on this website if you enter your app id in a post with special tags around it will generate and save a full description including pictures and blah blah blah of you app in a forum post. I'd like to do something similar to that.

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604886/how-to-get-info-from-the-apple-itunes-app-store-and-mac-app-store Apple provides json output

Answer (score 6):

You CANNOT do this via screen scraping.  Read Apple's [Terms Of Use](http://www.apple.com/legal/terms/site.html)

> Your Use of the Site You may not use
>   any “deep-link”, “page-scrape”,
>   “robot”, “spider” **or other automatic
>   device, program, algorithm or
>   methodology**, or any similar or
>   equivalent manual process, **to access,
>   acquire, copy or monitor any portion
>   of the Site or any Content**, or in any
>   way reproduce or circumvent the
>   navigational structure or presentation
>   of the Site or any Content, to obtain
>   or attempt to obtain any materials,
>   documents or information through any
>   means not purposely made available
>   through the Site. Apple reserves the
>   right to bar any such activity.

What you need to do is investigate Apple's [Partner Program](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/) which includes a program for developers and I believe would grant you access to an API where you would be able to directly query for and receive the info you wanted (such as app descriptions) to display on your site and perhaps even get a commission for sales you generate when people purchase something from apple via links on your site etc.

Odds are that the other site you see which is displaying such info from Apple's store, has an affiliate/partner arrangement with apple.  (and if not, it's just a matter of time till they get blocked from the site, find *cease and desist* letters in the mail from apple's laywers, get sued, or some combination of those three.

Answer (score 4):

You should really look at these first.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822380/how-legal-is-screen-scraping

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396778/legalities-of-screen-scraping

Knowing Apple, they'll probably sue you.  They have sued for less.  Or IOW who haven't they sued?

Comment: I don't think they'd sue. To clarify, there is a website called toucharcade.com on this website if you enter your app id in a post with special tags around it will generate and save a full description including pictures and blah blah blah of you app in a forum post. I'd like to do something similar to that. The website if very well known and I don't think they have any legal issues.

Comment: Also it's not anything different then what google does daily. They take information from other sites (web scraping) and display the information on their site for others to view. Just as long as you follow the robot.txt file there shouldn't be any legal issues.

Comment: The other site may well have obtained written permission from apple to do what they do.  They may even have access to an API for just this thing, which is given only to those with permission.   You are doing a lot of 'presuming' and 'assuming' here, better to do it right than suddenly find your IP blocked from using apple's sites

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save the information to your database then you might want to look at the program Appfetcher at http://www.altraware.com.

It uses the Xml that apple provides so there should be no legality issues.