# How to extract app information from the Apple store?

Tags: json, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm a newbie with Json, so I want to extract some app information from the app store, I found this question here :

[How to get info from the Apple iTunes «App Store» and «Mac App Store»](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604886/how-to-get-info-from-the-apple-itunes-app-store-and-mac-app-store)

It allows to get a Json file containing all the app information, but it would be nice if someone could show me how to get the price for example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where and how do you want to collect the results? Is this for an app or for some other kind of tool? In the reuslting JSON you have an array "results" where each element has a "currency" and a "price" value. Those can be queired rather simply. For example using the iOS 5 NSJSONSerialization (note this is an example, there has to be more error handling, handling of no / too many entries etc):

```
// assuming you have the downloaded data

NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:downloadedData options:nil error:&error];

if (error != nil)
{
    // error handling
}
else
{
    NSArray *results = [jsonData objectForKey:@"results"];

    // assuming you have 1 valid entry
    NSDictionary *result = [results objectAtIndex:0];
    NSNumber *price = [result objectForKey:@"price"];
    NSString *currency = [result objectForKey:@"currency"];

    NSLog(@"Price is %@ @%", price, currency);
}
```

Similar ways to access the data are avilable in other JSON frameworks, just grad the results array and every dictionary therein has a price and currency value.

Comment: THanks a lot TriPhoenix, I'm working on an iPhone app, and I want to get this information to be displayed in a uiTableView. Is there any way without limitation to the last IOS 5? I would my iphone app working on previous versions.

Comment: On previous iOS versions there is no native JSON framework but you can use third-party frameworks such as https://github.com/stig/json-framework/

Comment: Sorry, but I'm really in trouble, I used the code below and it works for a signle app, but when I'm trying to make an nsArray of apps, in order to use this data after that in an UiTableView, I get errors, some time without any indication, but sometime it shows that the array here :  // assuming you have 1 valid entry
    NSDictionary *result = [results objectAtIndex:0]; is empty. So how can i do this for many apps? retrieving their info? THanks a loooot

Comment: Is there some information in the `error` variable? Is the downloaded file definitely OK? Looking at the result for multiple apps you should be fine using the `results` array.